# Extra Faces showing up after I've exported project to .obj

Tags: export

This is my first post, so apologies if I'm missing some details or something similar.

I've been trying to work on an AR app recently, and been recommended Blender to make the 3D models to go into the scene. I found that XCode can convert .obj files to .usdz files (which is what I'm aiming for), so I tried to get blender to output my model in .obj files. Problem is...

[image]

this is what the 3D model looks like, and it outputs like this...

[image]

Has anyone got any ideas what I'm doing wrong and how I can get the file to output the same way it looks in the Viewport and when its been rendered?

Thank you :-)

Comment: I would guess that you have n-gons in your model which aren't properly converted by your conversion algorithm from obj to usdz.

Comment: You might try triangulating the entire mesh before exporting (Edit mode -> Select all -> Ctrl+T)

Comment: Thank you for your swift comments rjg and Robert. Robert, you hit the nail on the head on the first go! It worked a treat! Thank you for solving it! :-D